Crystallographic occupancy and Boltzmann distribution, how are they related?
I am experiencing difficulty in relating concepts from disparate fields and I would like to have your help to understand them:

The term 'crystallographic occupancy' can be defined as the number of conformers present in a PDB.
The Boltzmann distribution, on the other hand, provides the probability of a given energy.

My objective is to relate these two concepts within an equation. I am operating under the assumption that both the crystallographic occupancy and the Boltzmann distribution are probabilities. Therefore, these two probabilities can be multiplied together.

Is this an accurate interpretation?
How can I proceed to solve this relation among those concepts?


Long time no see. It's like you kinda compare a coin flip with a weather forecast, though, I think. You can't even see most of conformational changes with XRD. IIRC typical occupancy in pdb is a ballpark 50:50.

That´s true, ages. But. i.e. what would be the value of any thermodynamic property of a molecule in a crystallographic structure with occupancies 0.6:0.4?

I think it may translate to (statistical) entropy. At least in the simple case of frozen CO. Proteins... not really.

This is a long comment. To use the Boltzmann equation you have to assume that energy is free to move among all the possible levels, so that if for example you could instantly remove population from some of them (say by absorbing photons) this population loss will be refilled more or less immediately. If this were not the case then the distribution would no longer be Boltzmann but some other more complicated beast.
In conformers of large molecules the energy landscape is very complex with many barriers and wells each with its own energy. A conformer can get stuck in one such energy well. A Boltzmann population distribution will still apply to energy levels in that well. However, taken over all wells the total energy will not reach its minimum. (In organic chemistry being stuck in a well could be called a kinetic product)
This means that the whole system is not at equilibrium in the sense that if annealed in some way all the molecules would cross over all energy barriers be in the lowest energy conformation, assuming for simplicity that this is unique.
To make an equation then you need to sum over all these wells and add an arbitrary population to these as they will not necessarily be distributed according to Boltzmann. Thus the equation is very general i.e. $\sum_{E,k} g(E)p_k(E) $ where $p_k(E)$ is the probability of having a conformer of type $k$ in a well with energy (E) and $g$ the number of wells with that energy. Such generality is not very helpful really.
